# Function to function shortcode help

Tags: functions, shortcode

I have been with this for several days to see if you can help me. I need to take the data of the variable $result, which is 6, from the operation function to my shortcode, how can I do this?

```
operation();

function operation(){
$result=5+1;
return $result;
}


function my_function($result){ //
return  $all=$result+5;
}
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'my_function' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you would need this for but this is how you take the data of the variable $result from the operation function to your shortcode:

```
operation();

function operation(){
$result=5+1;
return $result;
}

function my_function(){
$result = operation();
return (string)$result;
}
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'my_function' );
```

Comment: Thanks you, I could not solve this

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function some_function( $a ) {
    return $a * 2;
}
function my_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $params = shortcode_atts( array(
        'value' => 0
    ), $atts );
    return (string)some_function( $params['value'] );
}
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'my_shortcode' );
```

When you use `[my-shortcode value=2]` on your page, it would be substituted with the result of `some_function(2)` (i.e. `4`).